# Url Shortener in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question,how to make url shortener?
for example i have this url "localhost/public/action/1"
become like this "/action/1"

I've watched how to make url shortener from Jeffery Way,but I'd like to make url shortener without using database,but get url as the parameter for the shortened url.Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to work it in your site? try to google `URL Rewrite`

Comment: what web server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your URLs shorter by pointing your document root directly to your `public` folder. In nginx you could configure it like:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name localhost;

   root /path/www/laravel_app/public; #this part

   ...

}
```

or in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /path/www/laravel_app/public
ServerName localhost

# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

This would save you from having `public` in the URL. If you wanna make it even shorter, add something like this in your `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 dev
```

Then change your server_name to `dev` which would make URL's like:

```
dev/action/1
```

**EDIT:** Are you talking about making an URL `http://path/to/a/very/long/exhausting/location` to `http://shorty/1234`?

Answer (score 0):

You wont need a web shortener. We you put this live, Laravel will exist in your 'public' folder, which will be your domain.

So your links will automatically become www.example.com/action/1

Your only seeing localhost/public because of your local server settings. Depending upon which web server you are running, you could change this, but it wont affect your coding or deployment.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions and approaches to solving this problem i am not using php but Java. i found this solution works for me and can be translated to php
The basic idea is that URLs should be unique every time,reducing collisions in the hash map. It works for any length of string.

```
public class MyUrlShortener {


static String generateRandomCode() {
    String s = randomString(8);
    String combinedString = s + System.currentTimeMillis();
    String result = StringHashing(combinedString);
    return result.substring (0, 7);
}

static String randomString(int length) {
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(bytes);
    return Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(bytes);
}

static String StringHashing(String s) {
    try {
        return getString(s);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("no such algorithm", e);
    }
}

static String getString(String s) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] hashBytes = messageDigest.digest(s.getBytes());
    StringBuilder hashString = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte hashByte : hashBytes) {
        hashString.append(String.format("%02x", hashByte));
    }
    return hashString.toString();
}

public static String encoder () {

    String code = generateRandomCode();

    return code;
}

public static void main(String ... args){
    String testString = "https://www.google.com/getGmailAccount/todaymail";
    String encoder = encoder();
    System.out.println(encoder);
}
```

}